# Convex Analysis Question

Tags: geometry, analysis

I need to show that $F(x,y,z) = (y - z, z- x, x - y)$ is Lipschitz on the closed ball $S = \{(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$.

I get that F should be Lipschitz since S is closed and bounded (I think?). But I can't seem to find the L-constant.

I've tried approaching this a few ways to show that $\|F(u) - F(v)\| \le a\|u - v\|$ for some scalar $a$ and  $u = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $v = (x_2, y_2, z_2)$ in $S$.

I see that $\|F(u) - F(v)\| = \sqrt{((x_1 - x_2) - (y_1 - y_2))^2 + ((y_1 -y_2) - (z_1 - z_2))^2 + ((z_1 - z_2) - (x_1 - x_2))^2}$

and $\|u - v\| = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2 + (z_1 - z_2)^2}$

I feel like this is close but I also feel like it could be a dead end. Am I missing something here or is there a better way to approach this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: Alright so the Jacobian of F is J = $\begin{bmatrix} 0 &\ 1 &\ -1\\ -1 &\ 0 &\ 1\\ 1 &\ -1 &\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and the Euclidean norm of this matrix is $\sqrt3$. It looks like I can then conclude that ||J u|| $\le$ $\sqrt3$ ||u||
that is:  ||F(u)|| $\le$ $\sqrt3$ ||u||. Am I justified in also saying that ||J(u-v)|| $\le$ $\sqrt3$ ||u-v||? I'm leaning towards yes, but I can't quite explain why. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, assuming your estimate is correct. Look in Rudin for a proof of the proposition I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint, there's a proposition to the effect that

> if $J(f)$ (the Jacobian matrix) is bounded, then $||f(u)-f(v)|| \leq
> M||u-v||$ for some $M$. You should prove this and find M.

Comment: Another hint: think about the norm of the Jacobian matrix of F...